# Microsoft Graph API office 365 : Is it possible to get Mail MIME type from the Graph

Tags: email, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Previously I was working with EWS - exchange mail library. Now we are trying to convert all our functionalities into Microsoft Graph API linked:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/overview

After investigation I didn't find any option to convert mail into his MIME type protocol....

Is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get MIME content of Office365 mail using Microsoft Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582626/how-to-get-mime-content-of-office365-mail-using-microsoft-graph-api)

Comment: I saw it possible in beta version

Comment: @VitalyT how possible? can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

you can make a custom requests using the IgraphClient object of Microsoft Graph API.

```
Object stream = graphClient.customRequest( "/users/ {id} /messages/ {id}/ $value") .buildRequest().get();
```