# Get MIME and/or EML Email Content/ format using Microsoft Graph API SDK .net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I have read the following article.
[How to get MIME content of Office365 mail using Microsoft Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582626/how-to-get-mime-content-of-office365-mail-using-microsoft-graph-api)

Yes we can get the mime value using REST call. However, my requirement is getting the MIME using .net core  Microsoft.Graph SDK.

I can easily get the Message using the following code in the shape of IMailFolderMessagesCollectionPage. But what I need is in the MIME shape/ EML

```
graphClient.Users[userEmailAddress].MailFolders[folderNameId].Messages.Request().GetAsync()
```

However, I am unable to find any method in the Graph API SDK C# to get any MIME content. Any advices? Thanks.

Comment: `graphClient.Users[userEmailAddress].Messages[messageID].Content.Request().GetAsync();`

Comment: Thats not getting the mime.

Comment: Hi Jay, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

I have tested in POSTMAN and [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) and I was able to get the MIME content in them as shown below.

[image]

Looks like the `Content` is not present in SDK yet but you can use the below code to get the MIME content.

```
var request = graphClient.Me.Messages["AAMkAGI0Mjk2NTQ5LTE4MjctNDE1Yy04Nzc0LWIxNzA0MDBkNDkwZABGAAAAAABAJhtsoNeXR49KeByGVNbsBwB0tR3-uC1cSqrKkE00IGLeAAAAAAEMAAB0tR3-uC1cSqrKkE00IGLeAADHJTf8AAA="].Request()
                        .GetHttpRequestMessage();

            request.RequestUri = new Uri(request.RequestUri.OriginalString + "/$value");
            var response = await graphClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);

            var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(message);
```

You can see the content as below.

[image]

I have referred the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57825319/how-to-pass-value-in-request-to-get-mime-content-of-mail-using-graph-sdk-not-ap).

Comment: I tried the code and it seems that I got the following error "Code: ErrorInvalidOperation
Message: ConversationId isn't supported in the context of this operation.", Any advices? thx

Comment: Please try with a different message id having only a single message and see if it can help.