# ErrorInternalServerError Getting mine content

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to get content (MIME) of an email via Microsoft Graph Api:
var mime = await _graphClient.Users [user] .Messages [mailid] .Content.Request (). GetAsync ();
for some users I'm get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7z3S.png)

Code: ErrorInternalServerError
Message: An internal server error occurred. The operation failed.
ClientRequestId: bd559710-a820-4c37-b386-fea7a72f3eec

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64763021/get-mime-and-or-eml-email-content-format-using-microsoft-graph-api-sdk-net-cor/64988083#64988083

Comment: Thanks for response, I have working code. I'm getting error for some users, not for all.

Comment: then isolate the issue with these users or the specific messages by checking them in postman/graph explorer to confirm it works for you or not (so that you can isolate your app) as well.